# Error compiling JSP on tomcat8 and java8

Tags: jsp, tomcat, java-8, tomcat8

I have a JSP which works on jboss 4.2.3 and tomcat6. However when I move it to java8 and tomcat8, it throws following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [768] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat/book_store/work/Catalina/localhost/bookStore/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/select_005fparameters_jsp.java]
bookData cannot be resolved to a variable

Stacktrace:
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:102)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:450)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:361)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:570)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
```

I tried adding following changes to /conf/web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>compiler</param-name>
    <param-value>modern</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
    <param-value>1.8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
     <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
     <param-value>1.8</param-value>
</init-param>
```

However I get the same error. I made following additions to /conf/web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>compilerClassName</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.jasper.compiler.AntCompiler</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I get following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Java compiler available
at   org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.createCompiler(JspCompilationContext.java:226)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:562)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
```

Tomcat startup.sh output:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat/book_tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat/book_tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/book_tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_31
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/java/jdk1.8.0_31/lib/tools.jar;/opt/ant/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant.jar;/opt/ant/apache-ant-1.9.4/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/opt/tomcat/book_tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/book_tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
```

### JSP

```
<d:table cellspacing="0" name="${actionBean.parmDetails}" id="bookData" requestURI="#wsTable" >
    <c:if test="<%= (null != bookData && "D".equals(((BookDetail)bookData).getParamType())) %>">
      <d:column style="text-align: left;" >
           <c:out value="${bookData.paramDisplayName}"/>
       </d:column>                    
       <d:column style="text-align: left;" >
          <s:select name="${bookData.jasperParamName}" id="${bookData.jasperParamName}" onchange="validateDateInputs()">
           <s:options-collection collection="${bookData.kvp}" value="key" label="value"/>
          </s:select>
    </d:column>                    
   </c:if>
```

Dependencies in pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.barbecue</groupId>
        <artifactId>barbecue</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-beta1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.barcode4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>barcode4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-anim</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-awt-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-css</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-script</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svggen</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-xml</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.bcel</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcel</artifactId>
        <version>5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.beanshell</groupId>
        <artifactId>bsh</artifactId>
        <version>2.0b4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.noelios.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.noelios.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.noelios.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.noelios.restlet.ext.httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.noelios.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.noelios.restlet.ext.simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-javaflow</artifactId>
        <version>1590792</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>displaytag</groupId>
        <artifactId>displaytag</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommon</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-compiler-jdt</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.23</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>pentaho</groupId> <artifactId>mondrian</artifactId> 
        <version>3.6.4</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.restlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.restlet.ext.jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.simpleframework</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.keypoint</groupId>
        <artifactId>png-encoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rhino</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>1.7R2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xfire</groupId>
        <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>serializer</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.stripes</groupId>
        <artifactId>stripes</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.04</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.37</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you paste your Java code and the portion of the JSP that contains the "bookData" variable (at and around line 768)?

Comment: If this is a Maven project post your POM. It is possible you are bundling JARs with your app that should be provided by the Container i.e. servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar, el etc.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined the `bookData` variable anywhere. And you're using a scriptlet expression in a `c:if` tag attribute. Use the JSP EL.

```
<c:if test="${bookData != null && 'D' == bookData.paramType}">
```

Comment: I modified the line to <c:if test="${bookData != null && 'D' == (((BookDetail)bookData).getParamType())}"> but this time I am getting new error  "${bookData != null && 'D'  == (((BookDetail)bookData).getParamType())}" contains invalid expression(s): javax.el.ELException: Failed to parse the expression [${bookData != null && 'D'==(((BookDetail)bookData).getParamType())}]

Comment: I gave you the correct expression to use. You just had to copy and paste it. But you chose to ignore my answer and use an invalid EL expression. So that's not surprising. The JSP EL is not the same language as Java. It doesn't have types. It doesn't have casts. And it doesn't need to use getFoo() to access the property `foo`. Learn the JSP EL.

Comment: I made the changes you mentioned. Still get the same error   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [768] in the generated java file: [/opt/tomcat/book_store/work/Catalina/localhost/bookStore/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/select_005fparameters_jsp.java]
bookData cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: That means that either you haven't actually done that, or that you have another scriptlet that is also using the undefined `bookData` variable, or that you have changed the JSP but haven't redeployed it.